# Unity HoloLens Azure Spatial Anchor- service unavailable or unspecified error found on

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I have downloaded the unity example project from Microsoft git and i used unity 2020.3.14 version to open the project, as per mentioned on the documentation, i have installed the com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.windows-2.10.2.tgz into my project.

Then i took and build and ran the demo scene, placed the cube on my floor and tried to save it, but unfortunately it is give me a "service unavailable or unspecified error found" error.

Any idea how it solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This could be multiple things. For example not specifying your Azure Spatial Anchor Service details (account ID, account domain + primary key) in your project.

Could you paste the link of the tutorial you were following?

Edit:
You have to download **both** the platform specific package and the core package as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/setup-unity-project?tabs=unity-package-web-ui#download-asa-packages). According to your description you only added the platform (windows) specific package and you're missing the core package. We currently recommend using the [Mixed Reality Feature Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/welcome-to-mr-feature-tool) to add both

Comment: I followed the Microsoft documentation only here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal